# firebase.database(app) arg expects a FirebaseApp instance or undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to set data to my realtime database on firebase. I have used the following code.
I am passing my database name as well as the region in my url still getting this error. Is there anyone who know's what is wrong with the code.

> Error "firebase.database(app) arg expects a FirebaseApp instance or undefined.Ensure the arg provided is a Firebase app instance; or no args to use the default Firebase app." I have also initialised the firebase config.

**Also I am getting the same problem while fetching data.**
[image]

```
import {EMPLOYEE_UPDATE,EMPLOYEE_CREATE,} from './types';

import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/app';

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';


export const employeeUpdate = ({prop,value}) => {

    return {

        type: EMPLOYEE_UPDATE,

        payload: {prop,value},

    };

};



export const employeeCreate = ({name,phone,shift}) => {

    const {currentUser} = auth();

    return (dispatch) =>{

        *const ref = database(

          'https://managerproject-8924c-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/')

        .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`);

        console.log(ref);

        ref.set({name,phone,shift})

        .then(()=> {*

            console.log('Data set.');

            dispatch({type: EMPLOYEE_CREATE });

            Actions.employeeList({type: 'reset'});

        });

    };

};
```

[image: this is my code and output]

Answer (score 0):

As Firebase realtime database documentation,

[image]

So, the code will be:

```js
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/database';

firebase
.app()
.database('https://managerproject-8924c-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/'))
.ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
.set({name,phone,shift})
.then(() => console.log('Data set.'))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```